# Append version number to output file for C application in Eclipse

Tags: c, gcc, eclipse-cdt

I have a version.h header file where I have the version of my application defined:

```
#define VERSION 0x0100
```

I would like to add it as a suffix to the output file. So instead of having myapp.elf I would like to have myapp_0100.elf. Is there a way to use symbols in the compilation options?

Comment: Wrong approach. 1) Learn what macros are. 2) You have to do that from your build script.

Comment: You probably aren't aware that you have specified the number as octal. Probably not what you want... Use a decimal number or a string instead.

Comment: Yes thanks. I need it to be hex value. I need to keep the version number defined in the header file. I was going to make a script to get the value from the file, but I wanted to make sure that there was no other option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the opposite. Define a variable in Eclipse and use it when compiling.
Go to the `Project Properties-> C/C++ Build -> Build variables`

Define a new variable `blah` with value `0100`. Then in the build settings, depending on your project type you can pass the `-DVERSION=${blah}` to the compiler. It will define the symbol called `VERSION` with the value given.
Now in `Project Properties-> C/C++ Build -> Setting` choose the `Build Artifact` tab. In the artifact name you can set `myapp_${blah}.elf`. Again, if your project is non-CDT managed, you can pass this variable to the makefile in order it to process it instead.